# Unable to write in the "E:\RepairSystem\public\images/categories" directory. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, file, laravel-blade

Unable to write in the "E:\RepairSystem\public\images/categories" directory. I'm using Laravel 10. this is error i get when i try to upload a photo in my project i have check all the permissions in my local folder but it still give me this error yesterday it is working fine no error occure but today it give me this error

following is my code to save image

```
 if ($request->hasFile('picture')) {
            $image = $request->file('picture');
            $imageName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $directory = '/images/brands';
            $image->move(public_path() . $directory, $imageName);
            $brand->picture = $imageName;
        }
```